# React Native Error - `Device: Undefined is not an object (evaluating 't.apply')`

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

First, the code:

```
 export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      count: 0,
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(this.inc, 1000)
  }

  inc = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      count: prevState.count + 1,
    }))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{this.state.count}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Before I run this code on an emulator (or even a real device for that matter), the IDE/compiler shows no error. But once I try running the code on emulator or a real device I get the error stated in the title of this question.

I was able to narrow down the problem by trying a few things here and there. Instead of calling `inc()` through the `setInterval()` method, I instead used a button to increment `this.state.count`. This seemed to work as expected on the emulator and a real device. However, using `setInterval` through `componentDidMount` does't seem to work!
Can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Here is a link to the screenshot of the error message I am getting when the code is run on a real device.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ughXqTB4VE1y5Kuz-BPrqbx68y4BLG9c

The device is Moto G5 Plus.

I am using the Expo (snack.expo.io) browser IDE to write React Native code.

P.S. I have not included stylesheet code and `import` statements for simplicity.

Comment: Try `setInterval(() => { this.inc() }, 1000)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, it work for me:

https://snack.expo.io/S1KcQ9qlV

Just change the function to:

```
 componentDidMount(){
    this.interval = setInterval(()=> this.inc(), 1000)
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

It because of redux store which included the redux dev tools and [image]`debug js remotely` is not on , turn it on will fix this issue

Comment: It works! In my case it was due to flipper's "createDebugger". I forgot to exclude it in production

Comment: I am getting the same on production in react-native. 
`    const composeEnhancers = composeWithDevTools({});

    const store = createReduxStore(
        rootReducer,
        composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk))
    );
`
Still getting the error